# Rails new "-T" option, does it create an app without tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am following this [tutorial](http://apionrails.icalialabs.com/book/chapter_one). In listing 1.1, it states:

> Be aware that we’ll be using Rspec as the testing suite, so just make sure you include the -T option when creating the rails application.

What does the `-T` option do in this case?

Comment: why the downvote? I wasn't able to find concrete information anywhere else :(

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you type:

```
rails -h
```

You'll see it explains the `-T` option like so:

```
-T, [--skip-test-unit], [--no-skip-test-unit]          # Skip Test::Unit files
```

In other words, this command tells Rails to skip the generation of `Test::Unit` files and folders. (`Test::Unit` is the default Rails testing framework.)

*Without* the `-T` option, two things happen by default:

1. The rails app is intialized with a `test` directory containing:

   ```
   test/controllers
   test/fixtures
   test/helpers
   test/integration
   test/mailers
   test/models
   test_helper.rb
   ```

   You won't need these directories or the test_helper because you'll be using RSpec, which has it's own folder structure and helpers.
2. `Test::Unit` test cases are auto-generated whenever you generate a model, controller, scaffold, etc.

   This is also unneeded because once you install RSpec, you'll be using RSpec's automatic spec generators.

Hope that helps!

Comment: @madcow so, when I add the -T option, will the test cases still be auto-generated when I generate a model, controller, scaffold, etc.?

Answer (score -3):

Yes it does not include any test file in your application. Also it does not include any gem related to testing while creating `Gemfile` for first time.

It's not good idea to use this -T option. Because each application should have proper test coverage.

Comment: If you're using another framework, It's probably better to use `-T` than to generate stubs and dependencies for a testing framework you won't use.